# QWeb how to add record to record set

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have the following variables in Odoo QWeb:

```
a = sale.order(5,6,7,8,)
b = sale.order(15,)
```

How can I add `b` to `a` so:

```
a = sale.order(5,6,7,8,15,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
 <t t-set="a" t-value="a | b"/>
```

[Source](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#set-operations).